# Anti-Reverse Engineering

Tags: .net, .net-reflector

I am trying to prevent my application from reflector,but can't not used .net code protection and obfuscation software because of some of the application feature are not working.so please give another idea or technique to prevent from Reverse Engineering

I have list of application  name used for Reverse Engineering [Link](http://www.overloadit.com/2009/03/01/net-code-protection-and-obfuscators/)

Currently, i am refer An Anti Reverse Engineering Guide article but how to used AntiRE.h doesn't know [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30815/An-Anti-Reverse-Engineering-Guide)

Please Help if you know about.

Application in VS2010 vb.net

Comment: And why is it that you need obfuscation in place? Hiding information in the code, such as password is usually not a very good idea.

Comment: @PabloRomeo it of course depends on how. From a purely security point of view, yes I agree (+1 for that as well); but for just; poc or a fun example, (nothing too serious) like "just to see" - It's quite a broad thing one can do. Maybe good maybe bad; but Yes I agree with you

Answer (score 0):

Use advantages of reflection's emit. so you can write some codes in `IL`:

```
static DynamicMethod Method6()
{
    DynamicMethod method1 = new DynamicMethod("Method5", typeof(void),
        new Type[] { typeof(DateTime) });
    ILGenerator il = method1.GetILGenerator();

    il.EmitWriteLine("In function 6: ");
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Box, typeof(DateTime));
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine",
        new Type[] { typeof(object) }));

    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    return method1;
}
```

You can do more with emit and UpCodes:

1. http://blog.alxandr.me/2010/10/16/an-introduction-to-system-reflection-emit-and-opcodes/
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y322t50.aspx
3. http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/28783
4. http://en.csharp-online.net/Attributes_and_Reflection%E2%80%94Reflection_Emit